# Display sentiment value in azure search

Tags: azure-search-.net-sdk

I am working on creating index, indexer, skill set for blob storage files using visual studio. Same index and skills will be used for azure search. I want to show the sentiment value while azure search output for each document when user trying to search some keyword. Can anyone help me how to do this?

### used the below sentiment skill.

```
new SentimentSkill()
{
    Description = "Sentiment based on sentence",
    Context = "/document",
    Inputs = new List<InputFieldMappingEntry>()
    {
        new InputFieldMappingEntry(name: "text", source: "/document/content")
    },
    Outputs = new List<OutputFieldMappingEntry>()
    {
         new OutputFieldMappingEntry(name: "score", targetName: "sentiment")
    }
},
```

---

I want to see sentiment value along with the metadata showing while searching.

Any help?

Thanks,
Bhanu

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add an indexer that maps "/document/sentiment" to an index field that is of type Edm.Double.  Then you should be able to see the sentiment in your index.

See full example of setting a skillset, and respective indexer at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-tutorial-blob-dotnet